# Terminal settings change behaviour of "sort -g"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal

I'm having problem with `sort -g` (i.e. general numeric sort) command when run via ssh. Example correct run on a file with 4 lines:

```
sort -g foo
9.1e-02
0.1
0.5
10.

cat foo
0.5
0.1
9.1e-02
10.
```

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm using the default terminal. When I ssh from that terminal to the same machine as used above, then I get incorrect result:

```
sort -g foo
0.1
0.5
9.1e-02
10.
```

It seems like some error caused by the terminal from which I ssh. I've tried to find an option in Preferences, but haven't found anything that seemed related. Please let me know what other info I should add.

**Edit 1**

`locale` for well-working system and terminal:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=pl_PL
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=POSIX
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

for the one with bug:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=pl_PL
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=POSIX
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Different `LC_NUMERIC` is the culprit. Now you (we) need to investigate why the difference.

Comment: Thanks. I've found that I had to comment `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Now `sort -g` works fine.

Comment: Great. [Write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and I will upvote it.

Comment: You should write an answer and then I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: Numeric sort in Poland is the same as in other countries. When I do `(echo 0.1; echo 9.1e-02) | LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8 sort -g` or `(echo 0.1; echo 9.1e-02) | LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8 sort -g` I get the same correct sort order as with other countries. So there must be some cause other than just the LC_* environment variables.

Comment: @Juergen Does `locale -a` confirm you have `pl_PL.UTF-8` available? If not, then no wonder it behaves like "with other countries". `LC_NUMERIC=foo` would do the same. BTW what other countries exactly? I have `en_US.UTF-8` *and* `pl_PL.UTF-8`, they do affect `sort -g`. It's about the decimal point.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, you are right - I didn't have the Polish locale available despite it is a large country. But I do have the German locale available and can reproduce the problem with `(echo 0.1; echo 9.1e-02) | LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 sort -g` (same result with `LC_ALL`). The root cause is the use of a locale that defines the decimal_point as comma (as it is in the German locale). I get correct `sort` results with `(echo 0,1; echo 9,1e-02) | LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 sort -g`.
So a workaround for the original question is to use `LC_ALL=C sort -g` instead of `sort -g`. I'm writing this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Ubuntu was by default forwarding `locale` settings. It was enough to comment out the line `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is the use of a locale that defines the decimal_point as comma (like in Poland or Germany) while having decimal points in the input data.

A workaround is to make the sort independent of current locale settings by using
`LC_ALL=C sort -g`
instead of `sort -g`.